# android canvas concatinate

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to construct a SurfaceView by reading in an array and using case switches to build the canvas.

so the question is: can I construct a canvas looping Y, by tracking X. loading bitmaps using BitmapFactory() into the canvas and then using 1 .show() to render the canvas to the screen? or will I need to call the canvas render for each of these (or will that through away the screen every time I do that)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're getting at, but for one thing **avoid using `BitmapFactory` in `onDraw`**. You don't want to be doing bitmap decoding at the same time as rendering. You should load your bitmaps ahead of time and keep them around in memory for faster drawing later on.

Comment: would it be possible to construct an array of bitmaps into the cnavas then in onDraw just render once, or would that cause a conflict for placing things ontop of them, or can I kinda use the z dimension to place things ontop of other things

Comment: You generally have to render them all each time you run your draw routine.

Comment: since R.java is simply a reference table for assets (deriving integers from "names"), and I have realized just how much memory could be taken up by holding an array of bitmaps. would it be possible to instead hold an array of integers (derived from R.java) values and then in a for each go through the array of integers placing them in the canvas? \n\n if this is possible I am having trouble finding a example of constructing the canvas in this way

Comment: This would require loading bitmaps from disk during `onDraw`, which would not perform well.